# SharePoint content approval message explanation

Tags: content, approval-process

> After disabling content approval, pending and rejected items may
>   appear in public views.

What I have an issue with is that ***may***.
A client requested if there is there any documentation/test cases describing when this actually happens. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a new item or when you modify an existing item in a list or a document library after you enable content approval for that list or document library, the item is marked as Pending. Pending items are only visible to the user who created or modified the item and to users with the Manage Lists right. Pending items are not visible to users until the item is approved. When an item is approved, it is marked as Approved and is visible to all users. When an item is rejected, it is marked as Rejected, and is returned to the user who created it.
If you disable content approval for that list or document library then item in pending and rejected state will be visible to all users.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825239